# How to execute function everytime i select row in kendo grid ui in angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am working on a functionalty . In this when i click on any row it should open in a popup. I have acheived same by calling selectionchange even as given below. But when i close popup and click same row again it doesn't hit my function as there is no change in selection.

So do we have any way by which we can always call my function when i click in same row again

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridView" 
                [pageSize]="pageSize" 
                [skip]="skip" 
                [pageable]="true" 
                [height]="300" 
                (pageChange)="pageChange($event)"
                [sortable]="{ mode: 'single' }" 
                [sort]="sort" 
                [selectable]="true" 
                (sortChange)="sortChange($event)" 
                (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)">
```

Comment: I think you will need to add your own click handler for the rows. Inspect the generated HTML in the browser dev tools and pick an appropriate selector for the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **cellClick** event handler:

[API reference](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-cellclick)

The Grid itself, the data item, associated with the row the clicked cell is in, the column, column index, row index, the original event, and some other information is available as event data:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: `
       <kendo-grid [data]="gridData" (cellClick)="onCellClick($event)">
       </kendo-grid>
   `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private gridData: any[] = products;

  onCellClick(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/TwdkXOTqN7y0J2ZtzCrH?p=preview)